# A few specific ServiceBus questions AutoRenewTimeout, Filtering, DeleteSubscription, PeekAndLockMode

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, servicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-servicebus-topics

I have a few specific questions related to service bus, that I wanted to get more insights into. I have read a lot of blogs, and a lot of documentation in regards to Service Bus (SB), and have implemented a solution that works using it. The questions that I am going to ask, how not been answered, or have been answered in an unclear way, so that's why I want to get more into specifics. So here they go:

1) Just wanted to get more detail in regards to "OnMessage" function for a ServiceBus queue. From what I understand it's not a typical while()/Receive() loop with a Sleep() interval, but in fact more of a "push" based approach, according to the documentation and my testing. So my question is if I set "AutoRenewTimeout" to 1 minute, then what happens to the thread that is waiting for a message to be received for that 1 minute before issuing a new Receive() operation..Does it sleep & wait for a message from ServiceBus to get "pushed" to it? or is it more of an asynchronous approach here where a thread is released back to the pool and only grabbed again to do work when a message arrives say 47 seconds into the 1 minute AutoRenewTimeout window that I set? (No, I am not talking about "OnMessageAsync" here) I guess this question touches the internals of WCF on which SB is implemented.

2) In regards to question 1), what would the significance be of setting "AutoRenewTimeout" to 5 minutes, or 10 minutes, or 60 minutes, besides the obvious cost of Receive() operation that would be triggered at those intervals? I guess from a customer's perspective, the less frequently I trigger receive operations the more cost effective it is for me, but as far as "waiting for the message" during this period from a service bus perspective / application perspective, what is the recommened "AutoRenewTimeout" perioud? Is SB more prone to drop a connection if "AutoRenewTimeout" is set to 1 hour vs. 1 minute? are more resources / thread usages being used up when the "AutoRenewTimeout" is longer? I wasn't able to find any clear answers to this on any post/blog/documentation that I've read.

3) I have a Topic/Subscription application deployed on each server that both sends/receive messages to/from a topic. Now, I don't want each client(server) to receive the messages that it itself sent out, I only want to receive the messages that other servers(clients) sent out. I was able to implement a solution using a SqlFilter(), but I was wondering if there's any other/better way of doing this? While talking about SqlFilters(), what is the performance impact, if any, on the speed of message delivery between subscription clients when using a simple comparison SqlFilter()? (I guess I could benchmark and see for myself, but I am just curious to take a peek at the internals)

4) In regards to PeekAndLock mode on message receiver, if in a hypothetical scenario, where a message is being marked completed at the time it is received on SB end, someone was able to physically cut the wire between SB end and the application VM, then that message would be lost forever, because the application would not receive it, yet the SB would have checked it off as being Completed. Is my understanding correct, that in PeekAndLock mode the message is being marked off as completed without the application end having an sure guarantee of ever receiving it?

5) In regards to deleting a subscription for a topic, that lets say has 100 messages in it that were never received, would that count as 1 operation, or as 101 operations?

Thank you for your time and effort in taking to read this. I would be glad to clarify any point if necessary. Abhishek, you seem to be one of the architects of SB, so if you see this post, I would really appreciate if you would drop a few comments:)

Thank you!